# Uppercasing filename in Makefile using sed

Tags: sed, makefile

I try to convert a filename such as `foo/bar/baz.proto` into something like `foo/bar/Baz.java` in my Makefile. For this purpose, I thought I could use `sed`. However, it seems that the command does not work as expected:

```
uppercase_file = $(shell echo "$(1)" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/\1\u\2/')
# generated Java sources
PROTO_JAVA_TARGETS := ${PROTO_SPECS:$(SRCDIR)/%.proto=$(JAVAGEN)/$(call uppercase_file,%).java}
```

When I try to run the sed command on the command line it seems to work:

```
~$ echo "foo/bar/baz" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/\1\u\2/'
foo/bar/Baz
```

Any ideas why this does not work inside the Makefile?

UPDATE:

The java files are generated with the following target:
`$(JAVAGEN)/%.java: $(SRCDIR)/%.proto`

How can I apply the substitution also for targets?

Comment: How does this help me in the Makefile?

Comment: What is `$(1)` supposed to be?   (I'm taking it the lines you show are in the global scope of the makefile as opposed to inside of a recipe or in a function definition).   You need to post more of your makefile to be clearer.

Comment: Make sure the shell and the sed path are the same within the Makefile as without.  GNU make also has uc/lc functions you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU Make does not replace `%` character in the replacement part of a [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) (which is basically a syntactic sugar for [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)) if it is part of a variable reference. I have not found this behavior described in the documentation, but you can look it implemented in the source code (the relevant function I believe is [find_char_unquote](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/read.c#n2234)).

I suggest moving the call out of the substitution reference, since `uppercase_file` obviously works properly on any file path:

```
PROTO_JAVA_TARGETS := $(call uppercase_file,${PROTO_SPECS:$(SRCDIR)/%.proto=$(JAVAGEN)/%.java})
```

If `$(PROTO_SPECS)` resolves not to a single element, but rather to a list of elements, you can use [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function) to call the function on every elements of a processed list:

```
PROTO_JAVA_TARGETS := $(foreach JAVA,${PROTO_SPECS:$(SRCDIR)/%.proto=$(JAVAGEN)/%.java},$(call uppercase_file,$(JAVA)))
```

> The java files are generated with the following target: `$(JAVAGEN)/%.java: $(SRCDIR)/%.proto`
>
> How can I apply the substitution also for targets?

Since Make matches targets first, and there is no way to run `sed` backwards, what you need here is either define an inverse function, or generate multiple explicit rules. I will show the latter approach.

```
define java_from_proto
$(call uppercase_file,$(1:$(SRCDIR)/%.proto=$(JAVAGEN)/%.java)): $1
    # Whatever recipe you use.
    # Use `$$@`, `$$<` and so on instead of `$@` or `$<`.
endef

$(foreach PROTO,$(PROTO_SPECS),$(eval $(call java_from_proto,$(PROTO))))
```

We basically generate one rule per file in `$(PROTO_SPEC)` using a [multiline variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Multi_002dLine) syntax, and then use `eval` to install that rule. There is also a very similar example on [this documentation page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) that can be helpful.

Comment: Good idea! However, `PROTO_SPECS` is a list created with a wildcard: `PROTO_SPECS := $(wildcard $(PROTODIR)/*.proto)`

Comment: Now I need a way to run the sed command on every element of the list

Comment: @AlexanderRössler Yeah, like [foreach](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function)

Comment: Thanks! Now I need to apply the substitution also for the targets (see my update). Do you maybe have an idea how to solve this as well?